# How to center a responsive page layout?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to use a CSS grid from [this page](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/), but I can't seem to figure out how the outside margins of the layout is done.

How do you define the content such that it scales responsively up to a certain width, then becomes a fixed-width, centered layout when the window is larger than that size?

http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/

Comment: Set a width for the parent div, then `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: Thank you! I got stuck on this for about half an hour, and then naturally find `max-width: 1000px;` two minutes after asking. I knew about the `auto` margins, just not the `max width.`